# In the review queue, what the difference between "recommend deletion" and "delete"?

Tags: support, review

When I recommend a post for deletion, sometimes after doing so I notice that other users have "Recommended Deletion", and sometimes one or two users simply have "Delete" by their name:

[image]

What's the difference?

Comment: Check their reputation levels

Comment: the ones that have privileges can delete directly. Recommend deletion puts them in the queue

Comment: @Sathya But in [this case](http://superuser.com/a/668632/201262), the post isn't deleted...? http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/166823

Comment: There's one deletion flag, and it requires three for the post to be deleted. It's like *voting to close* (requiring five votes) and *flagging a question as 'doesn't belong here'* (just put it in a queue). Only moderators with a diamond next to their name can delete (and close) without support from others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the highlighted user probably has [access to moderator tools](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and/or is a [trusted user](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

The former grants permission to cast delete votes on questions, the latter does the same for answers. This allows to the users who have that privilege to cause deletion of a post without diamond moderator intervention.